# NodeJs are module loaded in order?

Tags: node.js

I use the module `tough-cookie-filestore` which saves cookies to a local file. When setting `request` to use this cookie jar, it requires that the file already exists on disk. As I use this cookie jar in multiple modules, I want to avoid a big block of code at the top of my modules which checks if the cookie file exists and if not creates it, and so I made a module `initcookie.js` that does this.

My question is, is this a safe and good way to do this? `initcookie.init()` makes sure that the file exists, but can I be sure that it is run before `new FileCookieStore(config.cookiePath)` is executed?

```
var initcookie = require('../initcookie.js').init()
var config = require('../config.js')
var FileCookieStore = require('tough-cookie-filestore')
var request = require('request')
var j = request.jar(new FileCookieStore(config.cookiePath))
request = request.defaults({ jar: j })
```

Where `initcookie.js` is:

```
var config = require('./config.js')
var fs = require('fs')

// Initialize cookie file which stores the login info
exports.init = function () {
  try {
    fs.openSync(config.cookiePath, 'r')
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.code === 'ENOENT') {
      // File not found, so make one
      fs.writeFileSync(config.cookiePath, '', { flags: 'wx' }, function (err) {
        if (err) { throw (err) }
      })
    } else {
      throw (e)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One way to validate this, would be to place something long running / blocking inside of your init function and see if new FileCookieStore(config.cookiePath) is still called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way will work, but isn't the best way to do this.  `fs.writeFileSync` and `fs.openSync` will make sure that your code executes synchronously, but it would be better to use async so you aren't holding up the thread.  You could write

```
var config = require('./config.js')
var fs = require('fs')

// Initialize cookie file which stores the login info
exports.init = function () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    try {
      fs.openSync(config.cookiePath, 'r')
      resolve()
    } catch (e) {
      if (e.code === 'ENOENT') {
        // File not found, so make one
        fs.writeFile(config.cookiePath, '', { flags: 'wx' }, function (err) {
          if (err) { reject(err) }
          else { resolve() }
        })
      } else {
        reject(e)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This way you can use Promises in your other files and be sure cookiePath is created without holding up the thread.

The only issue I could see you running into would be if async leads you to run this function a bunch of times before it completes and so create a race condition.  To avoid that I would only call this function once at the beginning of the program and put everything else in the success function of that promise.

Comment: 1) Are you missing some return statements? Why `return resolve()` if open=success but just `resolve()` if write=success? Are they equal? 2) You mean that every module that uses the cookie file should be `required` in the main module in the `.then(function success()` ?

Comment: sorry about that, should just be resolve().  Yes, that's what I'm saying, or any way that you do the check at the beginning of the program will work